# How do I display the asterisks according to the number entered?

Tags: java

I am currently studying Java all by myself and I really want to learn a lot. I asked my programmer friend to give me some tasks and he gave me this.

How do I display the asterisks according to the number I input?

**EXAMPLE**

```
Enter Number:7
*
**
***
*
```

**I have written a code but I still can't get it. Please some examples , please?**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Diamond {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

         /*promt for input*/
         System.out.println( "Enter number: " );
         int how_many = input.nextInt();

         for(int i = 1; i <= how_many; i++ ) {
            for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++ ) {
                System.out.print( "*" );
            }
            System.out.println("");
         }

         input.close();
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to specify a type for `how_many`. --- e.g. `int how_many = input.nextInt();`

Comment: already did that. thats just a part of the whole code sir :)

Comment: So just a follow up question if I entered 5 should it look like:

    *
    **
    **

Comment: it would look like this:
// *
// **
//** without the slashes

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. You are just missing the variable declarations. Probably you come from a `JavaScript` background. Declare `int` before each one of the variables (how_many, i, and j) and try to compile & execute it again.

```
System.out.println( "Enter number: " );

int how_many = input.nextInt();

for(int i = 1; i <= how_many; i++ ) {
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++ ) {
        System.out.print( "*" );
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Also. I am assuming you have the `Scanner` object declared before everything

```
import java.util.*;
// etc, etc

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

I think I understood what you were asking:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println( "Enter number: " );

    int how_many = input.nextInt();

    outer:
    for(int i = 1, count = 0; i <= how_many; i++ ) {
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++ ) {
            if(count >= how_many)
                break outer;
            System.out.print( "*" );
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    input.close();
}
```

Comment: sir. take a look at the edited post. What I meant is that, if i entered 7, there would only be 7 asterisks, like this:
*
**
***
*

Comment: this is the result using your code sir, which is the same as mine.

Enter number: 
7
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******

Comment: I am not following you. What is the problem?

Comment: Sir, again, my question is that, How Do I display the asterisks according to the entered number (in a half triangle style) ?

Comment: take a look at the example above sir. at my post.

Comment: Your code is fine. If you forget the `Scanner` deleting everything about it and type: `int how_many = 7;` you'll see a triangle of that height

Comment: Check my edit and you'll see there is no difference.

Comment: im not asking for how many rows to display. im asking how to display asterisks according to the inputted number .

Comment: @NoobJavaLearner. I am not able to upvote you unless you edit your post. Make an edit and I'll do it

Answer (score 1):

```
class Print{

    public static void main(String argas []){


        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println( "Enter number: " );

        int  how_many = in.nextInt();
        int count=0;

        for(int i = 1; i <= how_many; i++ )
        {
            for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++ ) 
            {   **if(count==how_many)
                return;**
                System.out.print( "*" );
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }       
}
```

Add the condition to check whether the number of * are less than the input.

Comment: oh my god. Thank you sir !! can u explain me how did you get it?

Comment: why sir? His answer is what i am looking for ? Why are you downvoting him?

Comment: I think I finally understood what you were asking. I'll upvote both of you. See my edit. I made a slightly different version. Also, @mukulshukla's code would not be able to close the `Scanner` unless you close it before returning.

Comment: @NoobJavaLearner "Everything in your code was correct except you missed the condition which i commented in the code"

Comment: @LuisLavieri Could you please suggest me some articles for handling these things properly. I am also learning it.

Comment: What kind of things? @mukulshukla

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner; //program uses class Scanner

public class Print{

    public static void main(String[] args){
      //declare variables
      int num; 
      int x; //outer counter
      int y; //inner counter

      //use Scanner to obtain input
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter number: ");
      num = input.nextInt();
   
       //use for loop to generate the size of bar chart
       for(x = 0; x < num; x++)
       {
           for(y = 0; y < num; y++)
           {
              System.out.print("* ");
            } 

            System.out.println();
        }     
    }
}
```